# Name change of /dev/sdb4 to /dev/sdb5

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-10.04, system-administration

I have a partition layout on Ubuntu 10.4 as

```
sfdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 121575 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1          0+     60-     61-    487424   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2         60+   2492-   2432-  19530752   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3       2492+   4923-   2432-  19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sdb4       4923+ 121574- 116652- 937000960   83  Linux
```

/dev/sdb4 is mounted on /home

```
df -h /home
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb4             880G  202M  835G   1% /home
```

Is there any way to change the name of the device from /dev/sdb4 to /dev/sdb5 and also /dev/sdb5 should be mounted on /home without losing any data.

Comment: This question fits better on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

To adress mounting: As device names are generally not reliable (across kernel updates and I heard also when removing/adding other disks) you should change your /etc/fstab to reference your partitions by file system uuid

e.g. an /etc/fstab entry like

```
/dev/sdb4 /home ext3 defaults 0 0
```

becomes

```
UUID=YOURUUID /home ext3 defaults 0 0
```

where YOURUUID is the filesystem UUID which you can get as root with `blkid` (only use the string between the quotes).

As to changing the name of the device file, such things are done by configuring the udev daemon, though I am confident that changing the partition number is a **bad, bad** idea (why would you want to do it) so maybe this isn't even possible.

Comment: +1 Right on. I'm a little surprised it wasn't already using UUIDs... all recent Ubuntu installs I've done have by default. Definitely the way to go.

Comment: Jo So 
I do not need /etc/fstab entry.  My problem is simple I need to rename /dev/sdb4 to /dev/sdb5 rest of he changes in fstab I can make it using UUID as you suggested. I need it because I'm setting up a DRBD which needs identical device name.